# How to invoke firefox on windows through SSH from Linux machine

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox, jenkins, ssh

I am running selenium scripts on a windows machine.I have my scheduler algorithm in linux machine .My scheduler copies the files from jenkins to windows and will trigger test automation on windows machine.As part of automation firefox process is getting created on windows machine and the process is terminated instantly without opening the browser.My question is how to keep the firefox process keep alive and firefox window open for the entire duration of test run .

Comment: Just to clarify, 
Do you want the browser to open, all test to be executed(without closing the browser), after every test has executed the browser should be closed?

Comment: As part of selenium test case it should be opened ,but it is not opening at all

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have firefox version 47 installed, it is not supported currently. In future, you will need to install marionette/gecko driver. It similar to chrome driver and it developed by Mozilla.

For now, you can downgrade to version 46 if the problem is because of firefox version.